# Extract all the tweets by giving date as the parameter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I want to extract all the tweets of the week using twitter4j lib in java. I tried doing it like below

```
try {
            Query query = new Query("since:2013-04-01&until:2013-04-08");
            QueryResult result;
            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
            System.exit(0);
```

But, I ended up with an error message

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Missing or invalid url parameter
code - 195
```

So, how do i get the tweets by giving dates as parameters? Thanks

Comment: almost same, maybe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130040/android-twitter4j-getting-error-while-retweet-or-send-message

Comment: I've never used the library before, but I assume you are asking for too many tweets... there are an awful lot of tweets on twitter over a 1 week period

Comment: Am not bothered about the number of tweets. I just want to know about using dates as parameters for extracting the tweets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below snippet should answer your question (Date in YYYY-MM-DD format)

`Query query = new Query("#sad");`

`query.lang("en");`

`query.setSince("2006-01-01");`

`query.setUntil("2013-12-28");`

`QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);`